# in R, why does as.Date(Inf) display as NA, yet fails the test for being NA

Tags: r, na, infinity, as.date

An alternative title to this question is:
When is an NA date not an NA?
Answer: when it is infinity formatted as a date.

Converting infinity to a date results in NA being displayed, but it is not!

```
> BadDates <- as.Date(c(NA,Inf,-Inf))
> BadDates
[1] NA NA NA
> is.na(BadDates)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This causes confusion when trying to catch errors.
A work-around is to test for infinity and NA

```
> is.na(BadDates) & is.infinite(BadDates)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Is there a better way to manage this quirk of the Date class?

Comment: Strangely, if BadDates was specified as:  `BadDates <- as.Date(c(NA,Inf,-Inf,"Rhubarb"),optional=TRUE)` then `is.na(BadDates)` returns `TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is.finite(as.Date(NA))` and `is.infinite(as.Date(NA))` are both FALSE so `is.finite` will be FALSE for all the bad dates but TRUE for a good date.

```
BadDates <- as.Date(c(NA,Inf,-Inf))
is.finite(BadDates)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 
GoodDate <- Sys.Date()
is.finite(GoodDate)
## [1] TRUE
```

It works the same without dates so it is not specific to Date class.

```
x <- c(NA, Inf, -Inf)
is.finite(x)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

is.finite(3)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you have any idea why `as.Date(Inf)` displays as NA?

Comment: Presumably there is no other output that makes sense since Inf is not a valid date even though as.Date(Inf) won't result in an error.